# How to display model fuction in Django template

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-templates

What I am trying to do is to get the data from my model to show up a bootstrap modal. What I am doing right now is trying to pass the function data into the view and through the view I am trying to show the with in the modal. The issue I am encountering is:

Invalid block tag on line 47: 'show_profile', expected 'empty' or 'endfor'. Did you forget to register or load this tag?

Am I doing something wrong when I am trying to pass the data in or is something wrong with my tag or something else?

**Model**

```py
class mentee(models.Model):
    application_date_time = models.DateTimeField()
    # status = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    fname = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    full_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    lname = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    bio = models.CharField(max_length=1700)
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    objectives = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    years_of_experience = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    university = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    graduation_year = models.IntegerField()
    major = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    class_standing = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    country = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    student_type = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    profile_pic = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    linkedin = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    GitHub = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    website = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    resume = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    area_of_concentration = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    roles_of_interest = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    meet_in_person = models.BooleanField()
    preferred_years_of_experience = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    organization_of_interest = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    area_of_expertise = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    skills_desired = ArrayField(ArrayField(models.CharField(max_length=100)))
    gender_preference = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    time_preference = ArrayField(ArrayField(models.CharField(max_length=30)))
    location_preference = ArrayField(ArrayField(models.CharField(max_length=30)))
    preference_notes = models.CharField(max_length=1700)

    def showprofile(full_name):
       return mentee.objects.values().filter(full_name="Katha Benterman")
```

**HTML**

```html
             <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                    <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                    </button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                    {% show_profile %}
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

```py
def home(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        data = mentee.objects.all()
        profiles = mentee.showprofile(mentee.full_name)
        stu = {
            "full_name": data,
            "show_profile": profiles

        }
        return render(request, 'main/index.html', stu)
```

Comment: first of all, your `showprofile` method missing a ***`self`*** argument

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change this line

```
{% show_profile %}
```

to

```
{% for i in show_profile %}
    {{ i.full_name }}
{% endfor %}
```

and your method from

```
def showprofile(full_name):
       return mentee.objects.values().filter(full_name="Katha Benterman")
```

to

```
def showprofile(self,full_name):
       return self.objects.filter(full_name=fullname)
```

Comment: I do those changes but then I get this error 
`Invalid block tag on line 47: 'show_profile.full_name', expected 'empty' or 'endfor'. Did you forget to register or load this tag?`

Comment: I have used both when I use {%%}  I get the above error when I use {{}}, i get this error 
`Could not parse the remainder: '  %' from 'show_profile.full_name  %'`

Comment: So i just fixed the issue but nothing is showing in the modal at all a bit confused there

Comment: That gets an attribute error 
`'Manager' object has no attribute 'showprofile'`

Comment: check it now, and remove the previous one i said to change

Comment: Hey so I get this error `showprofile() missing 1 required positional argument: 'full_name'` Would i pass in self and the full_name in the view?

Answer (score 1):

{% show_profile %} would call a template tag that needs to be registered, hence the error that you are seeing. You want to display {{ show_profile.full_name }}.

Further, your model method should be changed:

```
def showprofile(self, full_name):
    return self.objects.filter(full_name=fullname)
```

Assuming you don't just want to put the very specific name out there that is in your current filter.